Not able to observe the logs from the class though its functionality is working fine
My aim was whenever a Async method is called my annotating any function as @asyn than a specific taskExecutor will be called and perform few operation such as passing the MDC value of parent to child and setting the thread prefix and other things
For that i created a custom class so now that class is called when a function annotated with @asyn is called so it hit the getAsyncExecutor() method and its log can be seen when i check the logs at Humio but this function than calls the taskExecutor() this method and the logs from this method cannot be seen but this function is given some task like setting the prefix of thread and calling another function MDCContextPropogator so even the logs are that class also coming but not from this method.
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncConfig.class);
@Autowired
private MdcContextPropagator mdcContextPropagator;

public AsyncConfig() {
    log.info("AsyncConfig constructor called");
}

@Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
public Executor taskExecutor() {
    log.info("Configuring TaskExecutor...");
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(50);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(200);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
    executor.setTaskDecorator(mdcContextPropagator);

    log.info("TaskExecutor initialized with corePoolSize: {}, maxPoolSize: {}, queueCapacity: {}",
            executor.getCorePoolSize(), executor.getMaxPoolSize(), executor.getQueueCapacity());

    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}

@Override
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    // Call the taskExecutor method directly instead of autowiring
    log.info("Returning taskExecutor for async execution...");
    return taskExecutor();
}

@Override
public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    log.info("Providing custom AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler...");
    return new CustomAsyncExceptionHandler();
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    log.info("AsyncConfig initialized and taskExecutor bean is ready");
}

here is the class that is supposed to be called once @async method is called.
Only logs from the method getAsyncExecutor() can be observed else no other logs can be observed neither from task executor nor from postContruct not the constructor
